# Looping trough a float

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The class `snum` is supposed to be a Float, and I would like to loop trough it to compute a simple average. However when I call `snum(1)` or `snum[1]` I obtain an error message:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

I am writing the following code:

```py
fh = open("mbox-short.txt")

for lx in fh:

    if not lx.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    else:
        z = lx.find("0")
        numbers = lx[z:].strip()
        snum = float(numbers)
```

When I call the output `snum`, I obtain:

```sh
0.8475
0.6178
0.6961
0.7565
0.7626
0.7556
0.7002
0.7615
0.7601
0.7605
0.6959
0.7606
0.7559
0.7605
0.6932
0.7558
0.6526
0.6948
0.6528
0.7002
0.7554
0.6956
0.6959
0.7556
0.9846
0.8509
0.9907
```

Comment: What do you mean by "loop through a float"? What values do you expect to see each time?

Comment: Is this homework like https://github.com/enixdark/pythonlearn-001/blob/master/week7/Assignment%207.2.py ?

Comment: In summary: you are given a file, you intend to treat one file as many lines, then discard some lines, then get a number from each remaining line, then analyse these many numbers. You are trying to use a loop to coordinate one / many dichotomy. Please analyse the problem and your code with focus on what there's one of and what there are many of. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `snum` isn't an array

One solution would be:

```
sum_nums = 0
count_nums = 0
fh = open("mbox-short.txt")
for lx in fh:
    if not lx.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    else:
        z = lx.find("0")
        number = lx[z:].strip()
        snum = float(number)
        sum_nums += snum
        count_nums += 1

print("Average", sum_nums / count_nums)
```

Or if you want to store your results in an array:

```
nums = []
fh = open("mbox-short.txt")
for lx in fh:
    if not lx.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    else:
        z = lx.find("0")
        number = lx[z:].strip()
        snum = float(number)
        nums.append(snum)

print("Average", sum(nums) / len(nums))
```